# Is there a pre-defined function in iOS that is activated upon the user typing a symbol?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-input

There are classes with pre-defined functions such as `viewDidLoad` or `touchesBegan:`. Is there one I could use for when keys on the software keyboard are pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not specific to either Swift or Xcode. It's an iOS question.

The answer is "sort of".

There is not a special function that gets called for a key press.

Instead, if the keyboard is attached to a `UITextField`, you can set up an object to be the text field's delegate, and then the delegate's `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method will be called as the user enters text. (At each key press, or on a paste). There is a similar method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` if the input field is a `UITextView`.